# Conditionally executing rule with FluentValidation for .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

I'm using [FluentValidation for .NET](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/)

I have these three rules:

```
RuleFor(customer => customer.Name).NotEmpty();
RuleFor(customer => customer.Phone).NotEmpty();
RuleFor(customer => customer.Birthday).NotEmpty();
```

And I want to execute this one only if the three others are validated successfully.

```
RuleFor(customer => customer).Must(IsUnique).WithMessage("...");
```

My requirement is not to use Chaining Validators like [here](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CreatingAValidator&referringTitle=Documentation&ANCHOR#Chaining) because the first three will not be evaluated if the previous of each one failed validation.

What I want is if one of the first three are empty, to display to the user the required fields. If all three are not empty, then I want to validate the last one.

Answer (score 2):

```
RuleFor(customer => customer)
.Must(IsUnique)
.WithMessage("...")
.When(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Name) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Phone) &&!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Birthday));
```

Comment: +1 It's not exactly what I want because I want to execute the last rule without having to repeat all the previous validations. The first three rules must be run before the last one. However, it's a good step toward the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Given your reply to Tomas's answer, I came up with the following solution:

```
public class CustomerValidator : AbstractValidator<Customer>
{
    private class CustomerFieldsValidator : AbstractValidator<Customer>
    {
        public CustomerFieldsValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(customer => customer.Name).NotEmpty();
            RuleFor(customer => customer.Phone).NotEmpty();
            RuleFor(customer => customer.Birthday).NotEmpty();
        }
    }

    public CustomerValidator()
    {
        Include(new CustomerFieldsValidator());
        RuleFor(customer => customer)
           .Must(IsUnique)
           .When(customer => new CustomerFieldsValidator().Validate(customer).IsValid)
           .WithMessage("...");
    }
}
```

If `CustomerValidator` has only two rules (counting nested validator as 1 rule), you can get rid of `.When()` clause to shorten the code further.